# Why aren't "internal" types in the main source tree visible in my unit tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I've got a Kotlin project in IntelliJ that is structured like this:

- main/com/foo/Bar.kt
- test/com/foo/BarTest.kt

where `Bar` is defined as:

```
internal class Bar
```

and `BarTest` is something like:

```
class BarTest {
    private lateinit var bar: Bar
}
```

I'm getting compiler errors in IntelliJ on the reference to `Bar` with the message:

> Cannot access 'Bar': it is internal in 'com.foo'

The tests, however, compile and run from the command line (via Gradle).

How can I suppress/remove this error when using IntelliJ?

My setup is:

- macOS 10.14.1
- IntelliJ 2018.2.6
- Kotlin 1.3.10

Comment: There's some debate, but the consensus seems to be that [you should only write unit tests for the public API](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=unit+test+private). At the very least, any tests you write against non-public code shouldn't be considered part of your production test suite.

Comment: the thing is i've setup projects like this in the past (i'm looking back at them through GitHub). i recently re-installed everything from my OS on up, so figured maybe i either missed some IntelliJ configuration setting that i had applied before, or that maybe the most recent build has started to employ this behavior.

Comment: Technically it is allowed (internal spans main/test in the same module) and there must be a misconfiguration somewhere. Or you are not in the same IntelliJ module for the main/test aspects of your project?  Did you create your project using the `build.gradle` as the source?  Maybe recreate your project by opening the `build.gradle` to see if you fix it.   (and check the modules) ... showing your directory structure would help, as well as the build file.

Comment: So, you know it normally works, and only you have enough evidence to know what is different than the normal.  Compare it to your previous projects, check modules, see what is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up two projects concurrently using the same IntelliJ installation:

- a former project in which I was able to unit test an `internal` class located in the `main` source tree (all within the boundaries of the same IntelliJ module)
- the current project in which I was unable to reproduce this setup

The fact that IntelliJ still gave no errors in the former setup led me to conclude the issue was not to do with my IntelliJ setup. As @JaysonMinard suggested, I looked at the differences in the Gradle configuration.

The difference was in the current project's top-level `settings.gradle`, I use the convention of renaming modules, a la:

```
findProject(':module-blah')?.name = 'blah'
```

...so as to refer to my Gradle projects by shorter names while having them listed contiguously in my project browser (rather than being scattered around with other files alphabetically). Removing this shortcut restored the behavior I was looking for in my unit tests.

Comment: interestingly enough... as I mentioned, I removed the line to rename the project via `findProject()` and IntelliJ doesn't complain about the reference to the `internal` class from the unit test... and if I restore the `findProject()` line everything continues to work... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯